# SKMaps Skobbler Implementation error XMLParser.m:14:9: 'SDKTools/SKTMaps/SKTMapsObject.h' file not found

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-errors, skmaps

I'm trying to insert SKMap SKRobbler SDK in my application, I had follow the tutorials
[here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec05)
and
[here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/iosTools)

With cocoapod I receive this error:

> XMLParser.m:14:9: 'SDKTools/SKTMaps/SKTMapsObject.h' file not found

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have to simply remove a part of filePath , with my cocoapod the import is:

```
#import <SKTMapsObject.h>
```

In this way i can build.